# Ubuntu is running in low graphics mode after installing ATI driver

Tags: graphics, ubuntu-12.04, ati

I have Ubuntu, version 12. I installed ATI driver and I'm getting an error running in low graphics mode.

I needed to install the driver because every time I update or upgrade Ubuntu, right after installing the packages the system runs in low graphics mode.

The answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error%5D) also couldn't help me.

Graphics card model: ATI Radeon HD 3600

Installing fglrx also didn't help. The ATI driver is still installed and it still runs in low graphics mode. What should I do?

Comment: I guess you asking at wrong place. Try asking on ubuntu forums

Answer (score 4):

First, you should understand that your graphics manager is messed up and that is what you want to fix. Now; here is a solution to your problem:

Here is a simple guide showing you how to do it step by step:

[A step by step guide to fixing "your system is running on low graphics"](http://simpledeveloper.com/system-running-in-low-graphics-mode/)

When you turn off your computer, reboot and hold these three keys:

**CTRL + ALT + F1**

This will open the terminal where you can enter commands that I am going to show you below:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Next enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm
```

Next enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
```

Next enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Almost done; When asked to choose, please select GDM and then finally:

```
sudo reboot
```

That is all you need to solve this problem!

Comment: After trying so many options this solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Let me try to help you :D

-Go to Recovery mode

-Enable network (so you have internet connection)

-Go to Root option (Recovery mode)

-When you are in terminal delete lightdm type without brackets {sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm}

-Then type without brackets {sudo apt-get install lightdm} (wait to install it)

-Then type without brackets {sudo service lighdm start}

-When it's finished type exit (you will get back to Recovery console)

-Then go on third option dpkg (Repair broken packages)(confirm with Y)

-When it's finished with installing packages type without brackets {sudo reboot}

-After reboot you will have back your Ubuntu! :D

I solve this problem after 1 day... Im a new user :D
Almost forgot i have Ati Radeon HD6770 graphic card, if you have Nvidia try it... Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue could be installing new programs in bin. I am not sure if that what is causing you the problem but I faced this issue because of the same issue. If I understand correctly, bin is supposed to contain only executables. By mistake I moved a whole big program to bin and when I restarted the system, I saw this error. A simple solution that I found is the following. Say you have moved the big folder ABC to bin.

Start terminal by typing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and login with your username and password.

Login to root by typing

```
sudo su
```

and providing password.

go to bin by typing

```
/usr/bin
```

type

```
ls -lrt
```

This last command will show all the files chronologically. See last few of them. One of those, say ABC, must be the one that moved by mistake to bin.

Remove that by typing

```
rm -r ABC
```

and then restart by

```
sudo reboot
```

And you get your graphics back!

Answer (score 0):

You can try and turn off the switchable graphics in the BIOS:

after that, it will be possible to use the Intel video card only with proper drivers on Ubuntu.

Here is the source: http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/07/ubuntu-1404-lenovo-g510.html

Answer (score 0):

In any ubuntu OS version 12.04,14.04 configured with the old graphic card  ATI/RS690 
change the setting as below 
etc/default/grub/

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset "

sudo update-grub

Restart